# How do I set jQuery accordion default to unopened? And toggle open/closed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I've got a page with a ton of accordions and when the first initially loads every single accordion by default is opened until I click on one. Then all of them close but that one and it then works fine from there.

HTML

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="ss_menu">
  <a class="ss_button">Accordion 1</a>
  <div class="ss_content">
    Content 1
  </div>
</div>

<div id="ss_menu">
  <a class="ss_button">Accordion 2</a>
  <div class="ss_content">
    Content 2
  </div>
</div>

<div id="ss_menu">
  <a class="ss_button">Accordion 3</a>
  <div class="ss_content">
    Content 3
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
/* Accordion controls */
#ss_menu {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.ss_button { 
    cursor: pointer;
    color: black;
}

.ss_content {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666;
  font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
  font-size: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

JS

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('.ss_button').on('click',function() {
        jQuery('.ss_content').slideUp('fast');
        jQuery(this).next('.ss_content').slideDown('fast');
    });
});
```

And the related Codepen: http://codepen.io/jacob_johnson/pen/zvdQGO

So my questions are:
1. How can I set them all closed by default on page load?
2. How can I toggle the one active one off by clicking the activate button again?

Any help would be appreciated.

**Solution to question 1**
Add `display: none` to my content element.

Comment: well that is not the jQuery ui accordion I thought you were talking about.... Set the css to hide them when you start the page. Add `display:none` to the css. and look into http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/

Comment: Thanks a ton. I can't believe I didn't think of that... Any help on question 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `display:none` in the CSS to start and change the code to be smarter on what it is hiding.

```
jQuery('.ss_button').on('click',function() {
    var content = jQuery(this).next('.ss_content');
    jQuery('.ss_content').not(content).slideUp('fast');
    content.toggleSlide('fast');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To do it using the code you have, you need a document.ready function which will close the content:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.ss_content').hide();

    $('.ss_button').on('click',function() {
        $('.ss_content').slideUp('fast');
        $(this).next('.ss_content').slideDown('fast');
    });
});
```

However, this will lead to your content being visible for a second while the page loads. The better way of doing this is with a CSS class:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.ss_button').on('click',function() {
        var menu = $(this).closest('.ss_menu');
        if (menu.hasClass('open')) {
            $('.ss_menu.open').removeClass('open');
            menu.addClass('open');
        }
        else {
            menu.removeClass('open');
        }
    });
});
```

Then in your CSS, you set everything to a default state of closed, but animate it to open when its parent has an open class:

```
.ss_menu {
    overflow:hidden;
}

.ss_menu.open .ss_content {
    opacity:1;
    max-height:1000px; /*set this to a height much bigger than you expect*/
}
.ss_content {
    max-height:0;
    opacity:0;
    transition:all 0.2s ease-out; /*or whatever transition you want*/
}
```

P.S. you can't have more than one item in a page with the same id - I have assumed this was a mistake, and used `ss_menu` as a class instead of an ID selector.